# Recommended way to handle backwards routing in Nativescript/angular?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

As our page numbers grow I'm starting to run into difficulties preventing duplicate frames, especially when using the side drawer.  If I navigate A -> B -> A, I will end up with 3 instances, 2 of A and 1 of B.  This means I have to somehow decided whether the navigation is a real navigation or a "backToPreviousPage".

Ideally I should just be able to put a route in and it would intelligently decide what to do, e.g:

```
router.navigate(['A'])
router.navigate(['B'])
router.navigate(['A'])
```

Should equal A - navigate -> B - backToPreviousPage -> A

Right now, my plan is to make a service to record the last route that was navigated to.  That way I can just do myService.navigate() and it will automatically decide if it should do a real navigation or use routerExtensions.backToPreviousPage() based on if the current route matches the previous.

Before I do that though, I want to make sure there isn't some glaring obvious way I should be handling this.  This kind of seems like a dirty way to do it.  To me it seems like the Nativescript router should handle this by default, but I've already confirmed that my A -> B -> A scenario re-runs the ngOnInit, and I haven't seen any options that could make this happen.

Comment: As long you call `navigate`, it just going to add current page to history and navigate to new route. You could navigate to a page how many ever times you want to, it just resembles the same happens in a browser environment. You may use `NSLocationStrategy` to determine what you have in your history and navigate back as needed.

Comment: That was my initial thought, but I've been looking at the NSLocationStrategy for a while now and I don't see anything that would help retrieve any sort of history.  Are you sure NSLocationStrategy is correct?

Answer (score 0):

The page router outlet should keep track of what is there in stack / history. Based on url segments you could decide whether you want to navigate back or navigate to new component.

```
constructor(pageRouterOutlet: PageRouterOutlet) {
    // `outlet` is private
    (<any>pageRouterOutlet).outlet.states.forEach((state) => {
        console.log(state.segmentGroup);
    });
}
```